# How does Pointer Arithmetic work after Pointer Casting?

Tags: c, pointers, endianness

```
int main() {
    short int a[4] = {1,1, [3] = 1};
    int *p = (int*)a;

    printf("p: %p  %d \n ", p, *p);
    printf("p+1: %p %d\n", (p +1), *(p+1));
}
```

why does *p = 65537 and *(p+1) = 65536?

Comment: Why do you think casting does change the behaviour of pointer arithmetics?

Comment: Note that dereferencing `p` or `p+1` is undefined behavior. We can explain how that undefined behavior seems to be manifesting in your particular circumstances, but it could do something completely different in slightly different circumstances.

Comment: Enable compler warnings and pay heed to them. You invoke undefined behaviour. Be happy your computer did not jump out of the window.

Comment: Your array `a` is an array of `short int`.  Due to the equivalence between arrays and pointers in C, it is meaningful and useful to access individual elements of array `a` using a pointer of type pointer-to-short-int, or `short int *`.  But it is *not* meaningful or useful to access them using a pointer of some other type.  What were you trying to accomplish here?  Did you expect meaningful numbers to come out?

Comment: compiling with gcc example.c -Wall does not give any warning

Comment: @IlDuke: That's because an explicit cast tends to silence warnings, it says, "Don't worry, compiler, I know what I'm doing."

Comment: this is an exercise i got from my classes it says :

Comment: given that  short int a[4] = {1,1, [3] = 1}; int *p = (int*)a;

Comment: All I can say is, there are some really bad textbooks out there with really bad exercises in them.  If you've presented this exercise accurately, it's the moral equivalent of teaching someone to ride a bicycle by instructing them to crash into a brick wall at high speed, then asking them to explain why they ended up with a broken arm.

Comment: *a = 0 T F; *(a+2) = 0 T F; *(p+1) = 65536

Comment: @SteveSummit: There is no "equivalence between ..."! An array is not called "pointer", because they are **not** equivalent! The indexing operator and most others in fact only work on pointers, not arrays.

Comment: @Olaf: I'm sorry, but you're wrong when you say "there is no equivalence".  The equivalence between arrays and pointers is a well-known and fundamental part of C.  (But yes, besides being well-known, it is also frequently misunderstood.)  See http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrequiv.html .

Comment: @SteveSummit: Please point me to where the standard states that and not just provide some third level reference. The first level reference (aka ISO/IEC 9899:2011) states that _Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator, the _Alignof operator, or the unary & operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type ''array of type'' is converted to an expression with type ''pointer to type ...''_ . ...

Comment: @SteveSummit: ... So, an array is converted to ("decays") to a pointer to the first element for **many** usages, but it is not "equivalent". A simple test with `sizeof(char [100]) == sizeof(char *)` on a popular platform will show one counter-example.

Comment: @Olaf: Of course arrays and pointers are not identical.  You certainly do not need to lecture me on that point.  But there *is* an equivalence between them, and for better or worse, the equivalence between them is often described using the word "equivalence".  Now, one could argue that the word is so confusing that it might be a good idea to try to avoid it, but it's a pretty popular word, and again, discussing the equivalence of arrays and pointers does not mean they are the same thing.  (Would you be happier if I said "the duality between arrays and pointers"?)

Comment: @SteveSummit: I'm fra from lecturing you, just correcting wrong claims. You might have a less common definition of equivalence than me. The common definition is it is bijective, which implies all features of one side applies to the other side. **For both sides!** There is no "A bit equivalent, except ...". And no, duality is also wrong. That would imply one behaves like the other. But the standard clearly states the array is **converted**, not treated "as-if". As much as for `(long)1` `1` is not an `int` anymore, but a `long`. Note the conversion might include a change of the representation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, to understand why `*P` is 65537 and `*(p+1)` is 65536 lets take a look at the memory:

```
00000001 00000000 | 00000001 00000000 | 00000000 00000000 | 00000001 00000000
```

I've split a byte by a space and a single `short int` by a |. Now we cast the ptr to a `int*` and it now takes four bytes instead of two:

```
00000001 00000000 00000001 00000000 | 00000000 00000000 00000001 00000000
```

If you input those binaries into your calculator and let it show you the decimal representation you'd exactly get those numbers. (Thats little-endian however, so the rightmost-byte is the `big` end which you'd input first into your calculator)

Comment: There is no need for that interpretation. Once you invoke UB, all bets are off.

Comment: i think in my case its explanation is the best i could get

Comment: @IlDuke: No, it just explains what you obvserve and a possible interpretation. It does not explain **why** it is wrong. For other optimisation, a different compiler (or even a version), an different architecture or even (if the compiler uses stochastic optimisations) after a recompilation, you might observe different behaviour. **Please** inform yourself what _undefined behaviour_ is and what it implies!